# How to start Tomcat 9 on Ubuntu 18.04 as a service in debug mode?

Tags: 18.04, java, tomcat

(looks like my question is evolving, after solving it I will edit it appropriately)

As in the title. I can run Tomcat as a service, but I have no idea how to run it in debug mode.

I've tried to run it in debug mode from terminal as in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689274/how-to-start-debug-mode-from-command-prompt-for-apache-tomcat-server

> For unix first export variables:
>
> > export JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
> > export JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
>
> and to start server in debug mode:
>
> > %TOMCAT_HOME%/bin/catalina.sh jpda start

So I ran

```
$ export JPDA_ADDRESS=8000  
$ export JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
$ sudo /usr/share/tomcat9/bin/catalina.sh jpda start
```

I got in response

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat9
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat9
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat9/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat9/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat9/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

`netstat -tpln | grep 8080` or `8000` shows me nothing.

However, when I'm running Tomcat as a service it starts listening on 8080 port. That's why I'm thinking that it would be nice to have it running in debug mode as a service, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Did you change `%TOMCAT_HOME%` to the dir that is `%TOMCAT_HOME%` or did you copy/paste `%TOMCAT_HOME%` into the service? Why run the service in debug mode? why not run tomcat in debug mode with the service off , fix the issue and then use the service?

Comment: Yes, I changed the dir, in my case it's `/usr/share/tomcat9/bin/catalina.sh jpda start`. I'm trying to run the service because I don't know how where is the issue and I can't make it to run it with the service off.
When I start it from terminal I'm getting `Tomcat started.` message but I can't access it from the broswer on 8080 port (when ran as a service, I can access it), which (the port) is written in server.xml file.